# How to find hinge point or axis of rotation point from top view using image processing?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a problem at hand where I need to detect/predict the coordinates of the hinge point or axis of rotation point using image processing. The image is as shown below:

[image]
[image]

I've used a method where I started with tracking the circular movement (in an arc) of a few feature points in an RoI around the default hinge coordinates (entered manually) in a configuration file. This circular motion of these tracked points happens around the vertical axis which passes through the hinge point. Now, I tracked these points from their initial position until the connecting bar made a particular angle (15°/20°) with the y-axis, I drew secants between these different positions (start and end positions) of the same point and drew its perpendicular bisector, which will ideally pass through the centre of the (concentric) circles, which is the ideal hinge point.

```
Eg:
y_intercepts calculated for each point
H0 (322, 42)                        
H1 (322, 64) (within tolerance, closest to GT)
H2 (322, 48)
H_avg (322,52)
H_groundtruth (x,y): (322, 61)
```

We need an accuracy or tolerance of +/- 3 pixels.
Now, the issues we faced in this ideal scenario to practical working of it is:

Different tracked points give different potential hinge points (different dots on the vertical yellow line), (few of which are very close the ground truth(yellow circle)), but their weighted/average (big green circle) goes off the mark. Quite frankly, this is a problem of too many in which we do get the closest potentially to ground truth, but we’re not sure, which of these points is the closest as we’re not to use the default hitch coordinates (entered manually) from config file.

Comment: would you please add more information about your tracking method used to track a set of features?  and if it's possible to add a real image of zone of hinge point ? because the nature of features may suggest a different feature detectors

Comment: I'm using Optical Flow to track the feature points. The real image is confidential. The tracking works fine. The issue is with deciding one/closest hinge point to ground truth gievn out by each of these tracked points traversing an arc as the vehicke turns left/right..

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use frameworks already implemented for image registration such as elastix. If you configure it for a rigid registration, you can get the transformation matrix and therefore the center of the rotation.

The problem here is that only one part of your image is moving. Before doing the registration, I would simply mask the region of interest by calculating a mask from the subtraction of the two images, to keep only the part where something actually moved.

Such approach could get a subpixel accuracy. You could also repeat it for multiple angles and average the result. Alternatively to the averaging, you could use the [RANSAC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) to know which hinge points are off (outliers) and exclude them.

[Here is an example how to do a simple rigid transformation with elastix.](https://simpleelastix.readthedocs.io/RigidRegistration.html)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response and sharing valuable info, particularly about elastix. However, I can't figure how image registration is needed here. Even if we can align the turned image with the original straight image, that doesn't solve the issue of detecting/predicting the hinge point.

Answer (score 1):

I intended this as only a comment, but it ended up significantly over the character limit:

The problem from an accuracy perspective (sorry, couldn't resist) seems to be that you're trying to use a planar euclidean geometry technique to solve a projective geometry problem.

Those feature tracks are only circular arcs in 3D world space. They're actually (noisy) elliptical arcs in 2D image pixel space due to the projection.

Your hinge rotation axis isn't a single pixel either, unless your camera's optical axis is directly aligned with the hinge axis. If that's not the case (as the perspective in the photo you added suggests), then your hinge axis is actually a line in pixel space, not a point, and different heights for the different tracks in model space will be 'centered' around different pixels on that line. So asking for +/- 3 pixel hinge 'point' accuracy is unclear, and so is measuring angles in pixel space in general in a way that doesn't account for perspective.

I only mention these details because you seem focused on measuring accurately. Often, those kinds of 2D approximations are fine for many applications, but high accuracy and precision from a single camera (if that's really what you need) requires better 3D scene understanding. (Or you could train a deep network with a bunch of labeled ground truth images and let it figure out the mappings.)

Now maybe you don't need such high accuracy for your application after all. In that case, simple affine geometry techniques like that mentioned in the other answer might work well enough.

Comment: We have transformed the image from perspective to top view, so we're essentially viewing the problem in a 2D geometry.

Comment: That's a common misconception about using homographies. It fools the human eye into thinking you're seeing the 3D scene from a different perspective, but you're not actually getting any additional pixel information. In fact, you're adding more distortion by flattening all pixels to the single transformation plane. However, if you're not interested in measuring precisely enough to tell the difference, then whatever affine transformations you're currently using are probably fine for your application. Just understand that you're ultimately limiting your accuracy with that approach.